# How to pretty a binary search tree in C in the style of the "tree" command found in Windows/Linux?

Tags: c, binary-search-tree, pretty-print

I am having trouble printing a binary search tree in the same way that the *tree* command would in the terminal. This is how my tree is currently being printed for a statement such "print 1 * 2 + 3":

```
|_ FUNC_NODE
   |_ PRINT_NODE
   |  |_ +
   |  |  |_ *
   |  |  |  |_ 1
   |  |  |  |_ 2
   |  |  |_ 3
```

but it should look like this

```
|_ FUNC_NODE
   |_ PRINT_NODE
      |_ +
         |_ *
         |  |_ 1
         |  |_ 2
         |_ 3
```

The "correct" C++ code for this is

```cpp
    void printTree(Node *node, std::string indent, bool isLeft )
    {
        if (!node) {return;}
        std::cout << indent << "|___ " << node->value << "\n";
        printTree(node->left, indent +  (isLeft ? "|    " : "   "), true);
        printTree(node->right, indent + (isLeft ? "|    " : "   "), false);
    }
    void printTree()
    {
        printTree(root, "", false);
    }
```

and I am trying to write something equivalent in C as a learning exercise. This is my code in C currently

```
void print_tree(struct Node *n, int level, char buf[256][256], int isLeft)
{
    //If the node is NULL, backtrack
    if (!n) {return;}

    char temp[256];

    //Print the current indention
    printf(buf[level]);

    //Place the current indention in a temp string
    strcpy(temp, buf[level]);

    //If it is a left child, add a pipe to the indention buffer
    if (isLeft) {
        strcat(temp,"|  ");
    } else { //Otherwise, a blank space
        strcat(temp,"   ");
    }

    //Store the new "string" in the buffer for the next call to use
    strcpy(buf[level+1],temp);
    //Print the visited node
    printf("|_ %s\n", numToToken(n));

    //Recursive subcalls
    print_tree(n->left, level + 1, buf, 1);
    print_tree(n->right, level + 1, buf, 0);
}

void print(struct Node *n)
{
    //Buffer for storing indentions
    char buf[256][256] = {{0}};
    print_tree(n, 0, buf, 0);
}
```

I suspect that my buffer is getting overridden at the current level on subsequent calls and I am unsure as to how to remedy this or if I should use a different approach.

Answer (score 2):

your c++ codes generates new strings when you do "+", and the parameter list is passing by value so a new copy is created, in any case they are not shared in the recursive calls.
The C code 'buf' is a pointer which is shared by all these function calls. You have to make 2 more copies for 'left' and 'right' function calls respectively.
For practice it is OK, but char[] is vulnarable to overflow if people abuse your code.

Comment: Thank you, for the response, I wasn't factoring in pointer decay. In order to implement the copies as you mentioned, would I have to use two char array parameters then?

Comment: yes. since there are already char[256] elsewhere you can do the same length, and copy content of buf into them. Essentially the parent function allocate memory and initilize content and hand over to the child functions.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, would my function take in the original char[256][256] as well as two new char[256][256] arrays? @Bing Wang

Comment: Sorry I missed that part in your code. To make a direct C++ analog, define ```void print_tree(struct Node *n, char buf[256], int isLeft)``` and create new arrays char[256] bufLeft, bufRight which are passed to the children. Your original idea also works if you return "int rowsUsed" instead of void and do some row arithmatic at parent level.